# How to probe/plot a three-way interaction in a Poisson regression model

Tags: regression, interaction

I found a three-way interaction (continuous x continuous x binary) in the prediction of my outcome (count) in a Poisson regression model. I am struggling to find guidance on how to probe and plot this - there's lots on probing three-way interactions for continuous (but not count). Would it be defensible to split my sample along the lines of my binary variable (group A, group B) and plot the significant two-way interactions. I realize this is not the best approach when the outcome is continuous, but I am wondering if I can make a case for doing that here.

Comment: What this model fits *is* a continuous quantity: it's the (log or logit of the) Poisson parameter.  To that extent, any method that works for ordinary least squares models ought to work here, too.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "probing" an interaction?

Comment: Thanks for the response! By probing, I mean understanding more about the nature of the interaction - what simple slopes are significant? In the case of OLS regression, I would typically plot the simple slopes at 1 standard deviation above and below the mean.

Comment: You can do that for any Generalized Linear Model without any change in your calculations (or software).